# passing named parameters to index template while using httprouter golang package

Tags: go, templates, server, named-parameters, httprouter

I just learnt how to use the **httprouter** go package and read many documents about it but
failed to use the :name style of passing paramenters toe templates when it comes to the index
page template.

ex.

My router code:

```
    func getRouter() *httprouter.Router {
    // Load and parse templates (from binary or disk)
    templateBox = rice.MustFindBox("templates")
    templateBox.Walk("", newTemplate)

    // mux handler
    router := httprouter.New() 

    // Example route that encounters an error
    router.GET("/broken/handler", broken)
    
    // Index route
    router.GET("/:email", index)
    router.GET("/read/all", readingHandler)
    router.POST("/submit/newcon", Handler1) 
    router.POST("/read/newcon", Handler2)
     
    // Serve static assets via the "static" directory
    fs := rice.MustFindBox("static").HTTPBox()
    router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", fs)
    return router
}
```

**Then i get this error:**

> 

panic: wildcard segment ':email' conflicts with existing children in path '/:email'

Comment: https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#named-parameters *"Since this router has only explicit matches, you can not register static routes and parameters for the same path segment. For example you can not register the patterns `/user/new` and `/user/:user` for the same request method at the same time."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it should work with /user/:email instead of just /:email.

Comment: Thank you so much @Riley Worstell, 
I finally resorted to receiving emails through URL query parameters and it works just fine.